# React-router nesting to show different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

In my `App.js` I have the following path:

```
<Route path="/register" component={RegistrationScreen} />
```

The registration screen component is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import RegistrationChooser from './RegistrationChooser';
import BookLoverRegistration from './BookLoverRegistration';
import BookLoverProRegistration from './BookLoverProRegistration';
import PublisherRegistration from './PublisherRegistration';
import LiteraryAgentRegistration from './LiteraryAgentRegistration';

export default class RegistrationScreen extends Component {

    render() {
        return <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={RegistrationChooser} />
                <Route path="/bookLover" component={BookLoverRegistration} />
                <Route path="/bookLoverPro" component={BookLoverProRegistration} />
                <Route path="/publisher" component={PublisherRegistration} />
                <Route path="/literaryAgent" component={LiteraryAgentRegistration} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    }

}
```

What i want to achieve is the following:

When visiting `/register` the `RegistrationChooser` component is loaded, and when visiting `/register/bookLover` the `BookLoverRegistration` component is shown and the `RegistrationChooser` component is hidden(not showing anymore).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the **match.path** property  **RegistrationScreen ** component like this

```
       <Route path=path={`${props.match.path}/`} component=
             {RegistrationChooser} 
                                                          />
```

Now change every path to use the **match.path** property before the path you wrote 
look at the first route and  change ever route using the same pattern 
 you can find more in this link

[React Router Api match](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match)

```
export default class RegistrationScreen extends Component {

constructor(props){
      super(props) ;
  }     
render() {
    return <div>
        <Switch>
             <Route path={`${props.match.path}/`} component={RegistrationChooser} />
             <Route path={`${props.match.path}/bookLover`} component=
              {BookLoverRegistration} />
             <Route path={`${props.match.path}/bookLoverPro`} component=
              {BookLoverProRegistration} />
              <Route path="/publisher" component={PublisherRegistration} />
              <Route path="/literaryAgent" component=
               {LiteraryAgentRegistration} 
           />
              </Switch>
           </div>
               }

           }
```

Answer (score 0):

use exact?

```
<Route exact path="/bookLover" component={BookLoverRegistration} />
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route

example -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zehsms

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `excat` flag, and trickle down the path.

So the parent router of this switch should be as follows:

```
export default class MainRouter extends Component {

    render() {
       return <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/register" component={RegistrationScreen} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    }

}
```

and then the child router would reference its route as follows:

```
export default class RegistrationScreen extends Component {

    render() {
        const { url } = this.props.match
        return <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path={url} exact component={RegistrationChooser} />
                <Route path={`${url}/bookLover`} exact component={BookLoverRegistration} />
                <Route path={`${url}/bookLoverPro`} exact component={BookLoverProRegistration} />
                <Route path={`${url}/publisher`} exact component={PublisherRegistration} />
                <Route path={`${url}/literaryAgent`} exact component={LiteraryAgentRegistration} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    }

}
```

You can get more detail in here https://learn.co/lessons/react-router-nested-routes